# How to ignore all bin folders except ones inside node_modules in Mercurial?

Tags: regex, mercurial

I am trying to ignore all * /bin/* in the solution except folders inside a node_modules folder. So:

```
/something/file.txt <- not ignored 
/something/bin/file.txt <- ignored
/something/node_modules/anything/bin/file.txt <-not ignored
```

The glob patter doesn't handle that, so I am trying to come up with a correct regex.

I came up with:

```
.*?\/bin\/(?<!node_modules).*
```

But something is still wrong in that.
I want to match any string containing /bin/ , but not if there is a node_modules somewhere before /bin/

Comment: "Not ignored" means there should not be a regex match? Try `^(?!.*\/node_modules\/).*\/bin\/.*` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you cannot use an infinite width lookbehind that you need here if you use your logic.

I suggest using a lookahead at the beginning:

```
^(?!.*\/node_modules(?=\/).*\/bin\/).*\/bin\/.*
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The lookahead checks if there are 0+ chars other than a newline as many as possible up to the last `/node_modules` that is followed with `\`, and then again 0+ chars other than a newline as many as possible up to the last `/bin/` (note: the last `\/` can be replaced with `(?:$|\/)` to check the `/` at the end of the string). This lookahead basically fails the match if there is a `/node_modules/` before a `/bin/`.

The `.*\/bin\/.*` matches a line that contains `/bin/`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tM0iS9/1)

Comment: Wow! This actually worked! I added an (?i) at the beginning to ignore case

Comment: Yes, an inline `(?i)` modifier will turn on case insensitive search.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your negative lookbehind  `(?<!..)` at the start of your regex

negative lookbehind : Ensures that the given pattern would not match and end at the current position in the expression. Does not consume characters.

with `/(?<!not )foo/`

this not match  : `not foo`

this match : `but foo`

try something like this :

```
(?<!node_modules).*?(?<!node_modules)\/bin\/(?<!node_modules).*
```